# Not able to get the video if the stream is created first in OPENTOK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opentok

I am basically trying to implement a video conference functionality using opentok.

I have two view controllers.

**Class A** that has a grey image(to tell user is offline).

- It calls setsession from class B to establish the session.
- uses ClassADelegate and implements `setUserOnlineImage` that sets the class A grey image to green.

**Class B** holds a method useronline.

- Has a class method `sharedinstance` that gives out the singleton instance of the class
- viewdidload ->sets a variable `type = 2;`
- setsession ->sets a variable `type = 1;`
- It also has a protocol "ClassADelegate"
- Protocol ClassADelegate has method `setUserOnlineImage`.
- Has a callback method `session:streamCreated:` that is called when a subscriber is created and `setupPublisher` that publishes the video

The flow is like this.

- first Class A calls the `setsession` from Class B to establish session.
- Then when a connect button is clicked the `viewdidload` is called and then the `setupPublisher` is called, view is modified loaded and all that.
- Now when a subscriber tries to connect `session:streamCreated:` is called. here when i try to print `type` value it comes as one, likewise many other variables also become `nil` which inturn results in just giving the audio and the video isnt seen.

where as if first `session:streamCreated:` is called (first video is received and then connect is clicked) the flow works fine and the print statement in `session:streamCreated:` correctly prints `type` value as 2.

Someone help me figure out whats happening.
I want to know why the `type` value is getting changed & various other variables become `nil`. This is preventing the video from showing. Am i missing something? Is any other instance is been taken(but I am using a singleton instance)?

Answer (score 1):

The flow you describe doesn't follow any of the known patterns of how UIViewControllers should behave. Specifically, you shouldn't need to use a singleton instance of a view controller. I think you need to reconsider the architecture, specifically the relationship between these two view controllers.

By the way, the `viewDidLoad` method is called on the view controller as soon as its `view` property becomes available, which can be before its on the screen. If the view controller is loading its view from a storyboard or nib, `viewDidLoad` is called as soon as that view is ready. Otherwise if you are implementing `loadView`, `viewDidLoad` is called after that method is finished.

Can you describe what Class A and Class B are trying to accomplish? It sounds like Class A is a view controller for some type of status view that shows a user's online/offline status. Class B sounds like its the OTSessionDelegate as well as the view controller for where the publisher/subscriber views will be placed. Why are these not the same View Controller? (generally view controllers are meant to control a "screenful" of content, unless you are using View Controller Containment). If these two view controllers are not on the screen at the same time, can you use a segue to pass data between them when the transition occurs?

**UPDATE:**

The additional information is useful for me to give you a recommendation. The thing I'm still uncertain about is if you actually do have these 2 view controllers' views on screen at the same time. This solution should work in both cases.

Outside of a segue, one view controller should not really be calling another view controller's methods directly (so calling `setsession` as you described is a bad idea). You shouldn't even set one as the delegate of another. At most they should share a Model object to communicate. The OTSession can be seen as a Model object. The challenging limitation is that when using the delegation pattern, only one object (you chose Class B) can be informed of updates. Rather than using the delegation pattern, I think you should use `NSNotification`s. In order to accomplish this, you should "wrap" the OTSession model in your own model object, setting your own model object as the delegate. Then you can notify both controllers of interesting changes as they happen. I've created a diagram to demonstrate:

[image: ios wrapped model that sends notifications]

In this diagram, all the downward solid arrows are owning references. `VideoConference` would be your own class and it would implement the `OTSessionDelegateProtocol`. On initialization, the `VideoConference` instance would create and own an `OTSession` instance. When something happens that Class A or Class B need to know about (such as the remote user coming online), `VideoConference` can send an NSNotification, which both controllers can be observers. Here is a [useful article about NSNotifications](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/).

Comment: Hi Ankur, 
    Thanks for your reply. I guess you have got my question wrong. This is what happens. Consider User XYZ has a friend John

Class A is a view that holds the friend details, connect button and shows if he/she is online or offline.

Class B is a view that has all the elements related to the VideoConference -> the videoview, endbutton, mute button, camera switchbutton etc.

Now like i said so find out if a friend is online or offline i should setupsession. so from ClassA using sharedinstance i call ClassB's setupsession.

Comment: So inorder to findout if a friend is online or offline i should set up the session and wait for my friend to come into the session which will be detected by `sessionDidConnect`. 
All the code related to the videoconference are in ClassB.